# Python: find the location of the maximum value in the k direction for every i,j combination in an array of shape i,j,k

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an `InArray` of shape `(360, 180, 10)` and I want to efficiently find the location for every i,j pairing where the maximum in the k direction occurs. So, my result will be an array of shape `(360,180)` where each value will be a value between 0 and 9.

This can be done using loops as outlined below, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this since it seems clumsy and inefficient.

```
import numpy as np 

result=np.empty([360,180])

for ii in range(0,360):
    for jj in range(0,180):
        pos=np.where(InArray[ii,jj,:] == np.max(InArray[ii,jj,:]))
        result[ii,jj]=pos[0][0]
```

(There will be instances where pos returns more than one value but in these instances the first element is all I am interested in).

Thanks to anyone who can offer help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
np.argmax(Inarray, axis=2)
```

See https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Comment: Simplicity itself! Thanks for the quick solution.